# Android:How to send missed call alert sms?

Tags: android, sms

If my mobile is not reachable or switched off when someone calls then I want to send sms to that particular person by automatically. How can i achieve this through code? 
Please help me.

Comment: if your mobile is off then how can you send sms?

Comment: I think, only telco (Your mobile carrier) can do this. If your phone not able to receive call or anything else , how it could send sms?

Comment: You will need to write your "CODE" for your service provider and make sure he uploads your "Code" to his server.

Comment: Is this possible to send sms when the phone backs to on state or reachable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This, I believe, is impossible. If someone rings you, and you have no signal, then how is your phone meant to know? If it did know, surely your phone would actually RING instead?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create service with phone state listener 
[ANdroid Development - Call state of the phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856884/android-development-call-state-of-the-phone)

and when you have call back send sms [Sending text messages programmatically in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578689/sending-text-messages-programmatically-in-android)